# "str object is not callable"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm trying to make it so the api will lookup the item code that has been inputted by the user. Everytime I run this code it allows the user to input an item code but rather than process that code into the api it says: 
"str object is not callable" with reference to line 14 which is `result=api.item_lookup('')`

The code below works when you remove `api.item_lookup=raw_input()` and manually put the item code in `api.item_lookup`, eg: `result=api.item_lookup('B017WMMAVU')`.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask("charity_third_page")

from amazonproduct import API
from lxml import etree
from lxml import objectify
api=API(locale='uk')

api.item_lookup = raw_input()

result=api.item_lookup('')

for item in result.Items.Item:
    print '%s' % (item.ItemAttributes.Title)

item=api.item_lookup('', ResponseGroup='OfferSummary')


print str(item.Items.Item.OfferSummary.LowestNewPrice.getchildren()[0]/ 100.0)
```

Any help on how to get this to run would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Because:

```
api.item_lookup = raw_input()
```

Is assigning a string (the result of `raw_input`) to `api.item_lookup`. Then you're trying to call it as a method. Maybe:

```
myStr = raw_input()
result = api.item_lookup(myStr)
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

You assigned the results of `raw_input`, a string, to `api.item_lookup`.  A string is not callable, but on the next line you try to call the method `api.item_lookup`.  Perhaps you meant to pass the input to the function, rather than overwriting it.

```
result = api.item_lookup(raw_input())
```